No data displayed when using Radzen Data Grid
I'm using Radzen Data Grid to display users from the AspNetUsers table but no data is displayed.
This is my code below:
@page "/contacts"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using BlazorApp1.Data
@using BlazorApp1.Models
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

@inject ApplicationDbContext DbContext

<h3>Contact</h3>

<RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true" PageSize="5" Data="@employees" SelectionMode="DataGridSelectionMode.Single" @bind-Value="@selectedEmployees">
    <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.Id)" Filterable="false" Title="ID" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" />
    <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.Name)" Filterable="true" Title="Name" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" />
    <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.OrgUnitId)" Filterable="true" Title="Org/Unit" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" />
    <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.PhoneNumber)" Filterable="true" Title="Phone Number" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" />
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {
    IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> employees;
    IList<ApplicationUser> selectedEmployees = new List<ApplicationUser>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        employees = await DbContext.Users.ToListAsync();

        selectedEmployees = new List<ApplicationUser>() { employees.FirstOrDefault() };
    }
}

I'm using server-side rendermode and SQL server for the database. Is there anything wrong with the way I implement it?

According to the official demo (Click Edit Source), you are missing wrapping the <RadzenDataGridColumn> elements in the <Columns>.
Your <RadzenDataGrid> structure should be as below:
<RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true" PageSize="5" Data="@employees" SelectionMode="DataGridSelectionMode.Single" @bind-Value="@selectedEmployees">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.Id)" Filterable="false" Title="ID" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.Name)" Filterable="true" Title="Name" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.OrgUnitId)" Filterable="true" Title="Org/Unit" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn Property="@nameof(ApplicationUser.PhoneNumber)" Filterable="true" Title="Phone Number" Frozen="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

